# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.0.30714

Tags: .net, dll, gac

This is error description and what we did in summary:

1. Error that we got as follows:

   ```
   Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.0.30714,
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its dependencies.
    The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
    reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   ```
2. Tried to access `GAC` using `GACUTIL.exe` but access denied, although I am the administrator of my PC
3. I removed and re-attached new DLL
4. Tried to used binding redirection in `web.config`
5. tried to add assemblies definition in `web.config`
6. tried to access `Machine.config` but again access is denied
7. Restart the server, webserver

After all it did not work. What I can do next to avoid this error. I checked `GAC` list and I did not find my assembly file there but I don't know how to pass by the permission to do it.

Comment: It is not the GAC.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  High odds that you simply have the wrong version of log4net.dll in your EXE directory.

Answer (score 0):

Look like [`supportedRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) is [absent](http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-net-35-clr-20-dll-inside-visual.html). Try add the element to the bottom of a config file

```
<startup> 
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/> 
</startup>
```